# TFS and clicking hyperlinks

Tags: coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I have some buttons in my web (javascript based) application. And I can record consecutive steps which I use these button in. The problem appears when I want to click a hyperlink. TFS doesn't recognize it - everything seems to be fine while recording a step, but later in tests it points my hyperlink with the mouse cursor, but nothing happens (no click executed).

In HTML it looks like:

Link 1

**[edit]**
I have noticed that the problem appears in Chrome, but in IE10 is OK...

Comment: Are you trying Coded UI Test? I guess that is nothing to do with TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using TFS 2012 update 2 or higher for this to work in Chrome.